# How can i use MVC compare attribute only insert form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i create a model class for my database user table. My database table hasn't got a confirmPassword field. But my class has it.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string password{ get; set; }

    [Compare("password", ErrorMessage = "Re-Type password!")]
    [NotMapped]
    public string confirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

my insert form has got confirmPassword textbox in html razor for compare, because i need it.

```
      <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.confirmPassword , new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.confirmPassword , new { @class = "form-control"})
            <h5 class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.confirmPassword )</h5>
        </div>
```

but my update form hasn't got confirmPassword textbox in html. So when i post my update form, ModelState.IsValid always be false. How can i use compare text field only insert form ? Because i don't need to use confirmPassword field in my update form.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using different `ViewModels` for Insert and Update operation. So that you can have (and validate) your own insert/update properties at the time of post operations.

Or else you can remove specific properties from Model Validation using `ModelState.Remove("confirmPassword");` (in your update post action), before checking for `ModelState.IsValid`, so that no validation will be triggered on that property.

Comment: for one field ModelState.Remove("confirmPassword"); is the easy way for me, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but I do not ask either the password. I add ModelState.Remove("Password"); and ModelState.Remove("ConfirmPassword") but it doesn't work. IsValid es false... what I am missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a different form that effectively needs a different 
`ViewModel` (different data validation requirements, required fields, etc), then you could create a different view model class for that view.

so for example, create a class called UserUpdate (that doesn't include the confirm password field), and map it as required to your domain entity's.